# Unable to operate the prompts of spot fire using selenium webdriver

Tags: selenium, webdriver, spotfire

If anybody has tested spot fire web applications using selenium webdriver please help me. Spot fire uses prompts as popups. And am unable to locate the prompts buttons to click.

Steps i followed:

1. Save the current window handle.
2. Get the next prompt window
   handle by traversing through iterator(While Loop).
3. Find the element on new window and click it. But when i printed current
   window handle and new window handle are same.

Below is my code

```
String parentWindowHandler = driver.getWindowHandle();//Stored parent window
String subWindowHandler = null;
Set<String> handles = driver.getWindowHandles();
Iterator<String> iterator = handles.iterator();
while (iterator.hasNext()){
            subWindowHandler = iterator.next();
        }
driver.switchTo().window(subWindowHandler);
(....My click functions)
```

I have pasted the fire bug element track below for "OK" Button on prompts.

Next

I have tried to take control using "class" but its throwing exception saying it cant take common/general class.

Please suggest me how to proceed to click a OK button on spot fire prompts.

I forgot to inform.My Prompt contains a "scroll bar" and "Next" button and "Cancel" Button. I need to choose items from scroll bar and press next or cancel button.

Comment: I think your prompt window is java script alert window, so you need to user Alert class object and call accept method to click on OK button

Comment: Hi Sadik i have already tried alert.when the pop up comes, it throws error saying "No alert pane has found". I think those prompts are not categorised in alerts are pop ups.

Comment: You might need to apply appropriate `Javascript` code with `JavascriptExecutor` to accept prompt without handling pop-up